# Cannot import name SummaryWriter

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm using Pycharm with python 3.9, torch 1.8.1+cu111 and tensorboard 2.6.0.
When I try to import SummaryWriter by:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
```

I get the following error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/heisery/Yaronhome/PycharmProjects/CSSC_pytorch/tensorboard.py", line 18, in <module>
    from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorboard
  File "/data/heisery/Yaronhome/PycharmProjects/CSSC_pytorch/tensorboard.py", line 18, in <module>
    from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter*
**ImportError: cannot import name 'SummaryWriter' from partially initialized module 'torch.utils.tensorboard' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py)**
```

This is my import list:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter('runs/mnist')

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

Comment: can you provide some of your code in order to help throubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Particulary your whole import list

Comment: This is my import list:

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
writer = SummaryWriter('runs/mnist')

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the line 'from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter' raises the error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'SummaryWriter' from partially initialized module 'torch.utils.tensorboard' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/init.py)**

Comment: runs without issues on my machine, mabe try to force reinstall everything using pip or `import torch.tensorboard as tb ` and then `tb.SummaryWriter() `

Comment: Rename your file to anything other than *tensorboard.py*

Comment: @Michael Szczesny ah yes, there is the circular import

Answer (score 4):

Bro
I have just solved a similar problem like yours. Just ensure that your filename is not set as 'tensorboard'.

Comment: this was actually my problem!